# Initialize queue.front as -1 or 0 in Designing Circular Queue

Tags: python, queue

I am learning the Queue from the problem [Design Circular Queue - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-circular-queue/)

> Design your implementation of the circular queue. The circular queue is a linear data structure in which the operations are performed based on FIFO (First In First Out) principle and the last position is connected back to the first position to make a circle. It is also called "Ring Buffer".
>
> One of the benefits of the circular queue is that we can make use of the spaces in front of the queue. In a normal queue, once the queue becomes full, we cannot insert the next element even if there is a space in front of the queue. But using the circular queue, we can use the space to store new values.
>
> Your implementation should support following operations:
>
> - `MyCircularQueue(k)`: Constructor, set the size of the queue to be k.
> - `Front`: Get the front item from the queue. If the queue is empty, return -1.
> - `Rear`: Get the last item from the queue. If the queue is empty, return -1.
> - `enQueue(value)`: Insert an element into the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful.
> - `deQueue()`: Delete an element from the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful.
> - `isEmpty()`: Checks whether the circular queue is empty or not.
> - `isFull()`: Checks whether the circular queue is full or not.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> MyCircularQueue circularQueue = new MyCircularQueue(3); // set the size to be 3
> circularQueue.enQueue(1);  // return true
> circularQueue.enQueue(2);  // return true
> circularQueue.enQueue(3);  // return true
> circularQueue.enQueue(4);  // return false, the queue is full
> circularQueue.Rear();  // return 3
> circularQueue.isFull();  // return true
> circularQueue.deQueue();  // return true
> circularQueue.enQueue(4);  // return true
> circularQueue.Rear();  // return 4
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> - All values will be in the range of [0, 1000].
> - The number of operations will be in the range of [1, 1000].
> - Please do not use the built-in Queue library.

I mimic Goodrich'st textbook [Data Structures and Algorithms in Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011DC80VY) and wrote a friendly readable solution

1, only three data(_queue, _len, and _front)

2, initialize  `self._front` as 0

```py
class MyCircularQueue:
     #Runtime: 76 ms, faster than 53.17%
     #Memory Usage: 13.6 MB, less than 7.24% 

    def __init__(self, k: int):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here. Set the size of the queue to be k.
        """
        self._queue = [None] * k #the basic 
        self._capacity = k 
        self._len = 0 
        #The first three categorize as a group, the 4th as the second group
        self._front = 0
        #self._rear is not necessary, because rear = front + length -1

    def enQueue(self, value: int) -> bool:
        """
        Insert an element into the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful.
        """
        if self.isFull(): return False
        avail = (self._front + self._len) % (self._capacity)
        self._queue[avail] = value 
        self._len += 1
        return True 

    def deQueue(self) -> bool:
        """
        Delete an element from the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful.
        """
        if self.isEmpty():
            return False 
        self._queue[self._front] = None #overrode the current node 
        self._front = (self._front+1) % self._capacity 
        self._len -= 1
        return True

    def Front(self) -> int:
        """
        Get the front item from the queue.
        """
        if not self.isEmpty():
            return self._queue[self._front]
        else:
            return -1


    def Rear(self) -> int:
        """
        Get the last item from the queue.
        """
        if not self.isEmpty():
            _rear = (self._front + self._len - 1) % self._capacity
            return self._queue[_rear]
        else:
            return -1


    def isEmpty(self) -> bool:
        """
        Checks whether the circular queue is empty or not.
        """
        return self._len == 0 


    def isFull(self) -> bool:
        """
        Checks whether the circular queue is full or not.
        """
        return self._len == self._capacity
```

Goodrich's design is very good to read with less efforts.

However, upon reading other submissions, the common practices are to initialize  `self._fornt` and `self._rear` as `-1`, thought it's effortstaking to read or write.

Excerpt a case  which performance better  than 98%

```py
def deQueue(self):
    """
    Delete an element from the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful.
    :rtype: bool
    """
    if self.isEmpty():
        return False 
    self.head = (self.head+1) % self.maxlen
    self.currlen -= 1
    if self.isEmpty(): #have to take care of self.head and self.tail
        self.head = -1
        self.tail = -1
```

```py
   #another submission which initialize front and rear =-1
    def enQueue(self, value: 'int') -> 'bool':
        """
        Insert an element into the circular queue. Return true if the operation is successful.
        """
        if (self.len == self.capacity): return False

        # To check if full
        #if (self.rear == self.front - 1 or (self.rear == self.capacity - 1 and self.front == 0) )
        if (self.front == -1):
            self.front, self.rear = 0, 0
        elif (self.rear == self.capacity - 1 and self.front != 0):
            # make rear start (case when element was removed from start)
            self.rear = 0
        else:
            self.rear = (self.rear + 1) % self.capacity
        self.data[self.rear] = value
        self.len += 1
        return True
```

Since python shadows most implementation details,

What' the advantage to take `front` or `rear` as `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have summarized the main differences between common solution and your solution are:

1. use `rear` pointer to flag the tail
2. when circular queue empty, set `front` and `rear` to `-1`
3. more `if` `else` logical branches

In general, I think these two solutions are not much difference, just have different tendency. If you want to know minor difference behind this, I will explain it for you.

In your opinion, you tend to use less variables and try to unify all logics together, and make code clean and easy-understanding.

In contrast, he wants to enhance performance (maybe just a little bit), and make a better abstract. I will explain it in detail:

1. **Enhance Performance**:

   - You can treat `rear` as "**trade space for time**". Every place related to `rear`, you will recaculate current `rear` by `(self._front + self._len - 1) % self._capacity`, but he just get from `rear`. He cache `rear` for high frequency usages.
     Cache can speed up query, but gain cost in maintain(when modify). So actually whether should use cache is based on the scenario. If query is more frequent than modify, you should use it. In this specific problem, if `Rear` used more than `enQueue` and `deQueue`, you can use `rear` to decrease recaculate cost.
   - He used more `if` `else` logical branches in `enQueue` and `deQueue`. It can enhance the performance a little bit by deal with specific condition. Specifically, it decrease `+-%` operation when empty, full or one-element case.
2. **Abstraction**:
   His solution is more object-oriented design. for a circular queue, which properties are important? Of course, `front`, `rear`, and `state`(empty, full or else). So he keeps `rear` and assign `-1` when empty to represent a special state.
   Good abstraction will benefit to functional scalability. For example, we want to add more function to `MyCircularQueue`, maybe `rear` and `state` is helpful here.

All of these is my personal opinion, maybe not correct, just for your information. : )